Add a separator in org-agenda day view between sorted tags
I use my org-agenda with items sorted by tags.
How can I add a separator in org-agenda day view between sorted tags?
Edit (based on the first comment):
(setq org-agenda-span 1                                  
  org-deadline-warning-days 10                       
  org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t                
  org-agenda-skip-deadline-prewarning-if-scheduled t 
  org-agenda-skip-deadlines-if-done t                
  org-agenda-restore-windows-after-quit t            
  org-agenda-window-setup 'only-window               
  org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done t
  org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done t
  org-agenda-start-on-weekday nil                    
  )

(setq org-agenda-sorting-strategy
  (quote
   ((agenda priority-down tag-up alpha-up)
    (todo priority-down alpha-up)
    (tags tag-up priority-down alpha-up))))

To show what my org-agenda looks like:


Can you please add the setting of org-agenda-custom-commands that you use to produce the sorted-tag agenda? An example of what it looks like now and what you would like it to look like would also help.

I just did an edit on the main post with the agenda code. I am trying to set this up for the default "agenda for the current week or day." (Not necessarily in my custom agendas)

I think the best you can do is to add a function to org-agenda-finalize-hook: at that point, the *Org Agenda* buffer is almost complete, but is still writable. So the function will have to analyze the buffer, find the entries with tags and insert the separator at the appropriate places. Not too hard, but not particularly elegant. Maybe there is a better way, but I haven't found one yet.

Here's an implementation following the guidelines in my last comment: we write a function to implement what you want and add it to org-agenda-finalize-hook:
#+begin_src elisp :results drawer
  (defun my/org-agenda-add-separators ()
    "Add separators between agenda entries to distinguish different
  tags. The daily/weekly agenda is assumed to be sorted by tags, so we
  just march down, get the tag list and if it is different from the
  previous one, we insert a separator (an empty line in this POC)."
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((prev-tag-list nil))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (let ((current-tag-list (plist-get (text-properties-at (point)) 'tags)))
          (when (not (equal current-tag-list prev-tag-list))
            (insert "\n")
            (setq prev-tag-list current-tag-list)))
        (forward-line 1))))
  
  (add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook #'my/org-agenda-add-separators)
#+end_src

The hook is run after the *Org Agenda* buffer has been populated but just before it is made read-only.
The basic idea is that we march down the lines in the *Org Agenda* buffer and for each line, we get the tags and compare them to the tags of the previous line: if they not equal, we insert a separator (here just an empty line, but you can change that as you wish), and remember the new tag list.
The agenda makes heavy use of text properties and that's what allows us to write such a concise function. I wouldn't call it elegant but it's not too bad.

You are an elisp magician! I had put this on my Someday TODO list, as I am a beginner in elisp. Where would you suggest I go to start learning more elisp so I could even figure out to use things like "eobp" or "plist-get"?

Emacs is a large playground. I recommend you start by learning how to use the Help system and the Info system in Emacs. E.g. say C-h f eobp to get the doc string of the function eobp, and C-h i g(emacs) to get to the Emacs manual. The more familiar you are with these two systems, the smoother your journey is going to be. The manuals are available online, but I recommend reading them in Emacs with Info

The Emacs manual and the Info manual should be your first ports of call. You don't have to read them cover to cover: they are reference manuals, so you can read selectively. The Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp is a useful first step into Elisp programming and is more like a book that you would read from beginning to end.

Ultimately the Emacs Lisp Reference manual is going to be indispensable but again it's a (large) reference manual, so read selectively. And try to use Info: all the manuals are available from within Emacs, so you don't have to switch to your browser to read them: just say C-h i to get started.

Thanks! "C-h i" is my new friend!
